# Can I limit the search of a site to the level 1 (ie. I want to exclude all content from subsites)?

Tags: sub-site

I have a site with apps and subsites and When I do a search in the main site, I want to block all results from the subsites.

Example : If I have an article about Yellow bananas in my subsite named Fruits, and I do a search in the main site for "Yellow", I don't want to see the article about Yellow Bananas from the subsite Fruits in the results.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your own search page within your site. (site pages > add a wiki page. I recommend the layout with the header and two columns)
2. Add all 3 search web parts to the page. (Search box(top zone), refiners(right zone/column), and search results(left zone/column).
3. save the page (to save your web parts to the page)
4. modify the page and then modify the search results web part to change the query to only return results on the current site
   [image]
5. Now set your site to default to your search page instead of the default parent. (Settings > Site settings > Search Settings)
6. uncheck the inherit box and paste the URL to your custom search page in the filed.
   [image]